# Parse xPath like string and create xml document using jdom

Tags: xml, jdom

I am trying to build some utility to create document model from a string like xpath:

setName(document,"college/class/student[14]@name","Rob"),

so, this function should create nodes and attributes in the document if it doesn't exist and move on  if the node already exists.

I am failing to validate and implement the '[14]' part, ie creating 13 blank  followed with adding attribute name with value of "Rob". As, there can also be cases of

setName(document,"university/college[2]/class[12]/student[14]@name","Rob")\

Thanks in Advance
Tirthankar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a recursive parser that is able to handle the indexes.